# Where to store created PDF files on ASP .NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a site that's going to allow users to create PDF files and access them later on. What's the best way to store and access them? Shall I save them to database as binary stream or put somewhere in server's directory?

Comment: you can create a folder and store pdf files there otherwise you will have to write code to fetch pdf byte array from database and generate pdf file from that byte array.